# Derivation of the moment generating function of the geometric distribution - why is this wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $P(k,X)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$.

When deriving the moment generating function I start off as follows:

$E[e^{kt}X]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{kt}p(1-p)^{k-1}$.

How I end up rearranging this is as follows:

$\frac{p}{1-p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{kt}(1-p)^k=\frac{p}{1-p}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(e^{t}(1-p))^k=\frac{p}{1-p}\frac{1}{1-e^t(1-p)}$

I'm obviously not arriving at the correct answer, but I want to know why this derivation is wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Formula: Let $|q|<1$ then we have  $$(\star) \ \ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} q^k = \frac{q}{1-q}.$$ 
We use this fact for the calculations of MGF
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{tk}(1-p)^k=\frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{t}(1-p)\right)^k $$
now let us apply $(\star)$ to obtain $$\frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\underbrace{e^{t}(1-p)}_{=:q}\right)^k = \frac{p}{1-p}\frac{\overbrace{e^t(1-p)}^{q}}{\underbrace{1-e^t(1-p)}_{1-q}} = \frac{pe^t}{1-e^t(1-p)}.$$

It is well-defined for all $t< -\ln(1-p)$.

Comment: Where is that $e^t$ in the numerator coming from?

Comment: I edited my answer to put more explanation. You have to use the formula for the sum of geometric series when you start with $k=1$, not $k=0$ (bottom of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes.  I kept not observing that this series began at 1 instead of 0.